# How to restrict resource acess with an api gateway

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I'm implementing a simple microservice-based project and I'm facing some doubts regarding authentication. My doubt is more about best practices than what to do in the technology.

WHAT I HAVE:

- lets say I have a couple of APIs
- also have a API gateway that is responsible for routing and authentication
- I'm using an identity provider (keycloak) for the authentication (JWT based)

WHAT I WANT TO KNOW:

Lets say i have an endpoint like `api/user/<user_id>` which works with a POST request and it changes information about an user.

For this, not only I need to check if is an authenticated/allowed user by i also have to check if the user trying to access it is the own user.

My question is, is it best to do it in the API gateway or the API gateway needs to pass the JWT to the API so it can check this on the controller ?

- I'm using spring-boot for the apis
- Netflix's Zuul proxy for the API gateway
- Keycloak to handle authentications

Answer (score 1):

The sole purpose of API Gateway is **Request Routing, Authentication and Load Balancing**.

Whether a user has authority to modify should be checked in that micro-service and decision should be taken.